# Gradle task using artifact from repository as build tool

Tags: gradle

How can I execute a tool hosted on a repository in a Gradle task?

In my specific case, I am using Gradle to build an Android app. I have added a task to encode some protobuf data from text to binary format:

```
task encodeData {
    ext.resDir = file("$buildDir/binary_proto")
    def inputDir = 'text_pb'
    def outputDir = "$resDir/raw"
    inputs.dir inputDir
    outputs.dir outputDir

    doLast {
        file(outputDir).mkdirs()
        file(inputDir).eachFile { inputFile ->
            exec {
                commandLine 'sh', '-c', "protoc --encode=MyMessage src/main/proto/my_proto.proto < \
                  \"$inputFile\" > \"$outputDir/$inputFile.name\""
            }
        }
    }
}

android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.registerResGeneratingTask(encodeData, encodeData.resDir)
    }
}
```

The above works but **only if protoc is manually installed**. I would like to instead use the [pre-compiled protoc on Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/3.0.0/) (just like the [recommended configuration of the protobuf plugin](https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin#locate-external-executables)). I cargo-culted from [this thread](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/can-dependencies-be-used-to-manage-runtime-executables-if-so-how/7384) and arrived at:

```
repositories { mavenCentral() }

configurations {
    proto_encode
}

dependencies {
    proto_encode 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
}

println configurations['proto_encode'].singleFile
```

However this produces an error `Expected configuration ':app:proto_encode' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.` (I also tried adding an `artifact` clause to the dependency but wasn't sure how to set the parameters). Presumably I need to somehow tell Gradle that this tool is to be run on the host (as part of the build process) rather than target (ie Android device) so it knows which version to pick. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0` you tell Gradle you want the JAR artifact with the default (absent) qualifier.

Instead you have to tell Gradle wich qualifier and what artifact you want. If you e. g. want the 64-bit Windows version, you need `windows-x86_64` as qualifier and `exe` as artifact type, this would then be `com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0:windows-x86_64@exe`.

So you need to determine what system you are currently building on and then determine the qualifier accordingly. And then you can use that determined qualifier in the dependency string.

At http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.protobuf%22%20AND%20a%3A%22protoc%22 you can see which artifacts are present for your dependency.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Is there a way to have gradle determine the host system, so that the build script can be more portable?

Comment: A Gradle script is based on Groovy, so you can use any Groovy or Java code to determine the OS, usually you do it by inspecting the system properties or by using some library that most probably inspects the system properties.